# Extra argument in call error mystery

Tags: ios, swift, swift-playground

I had some older Swift code that used to compile and work where I was using the .append to build out a data structure dynamically.  After upgrading to a few compiler versions newer I am getting the dreaded "Extra Argument '  ' in call" error.  I reduced the code down to this:

```
struct  EHSearch {
    let EHcategory : String = ""
    let EHname : String = ""
}

var  myEHSearch = [EHSearch]()

// Call to dynamically append the results
// Extra argument: 'EHcategory' in call

myEHSearch.append(EHSearch(EHcategory: "Food", EHname: "Joes Crab Shack"))
```

I can't see anything so far in searching on what has changed to cause this one so seeking guidance here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you have `let` in your struct.
Define your structure like this:

```
struct EHSearch {
    var EHcategory : String = ""
    var EHname : String = ""
}
```

If you have constants in your `struct`, you can not provide them initial value while creating new structure instances. The automatically-generated member-wise initializer doesn't accept `let` members as parameters of the initializer of struct.

Comment: Perfect.  That worked.   I guess the earlier language / compiler versions did not clamp down on this like they do now.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your intentions with the struct's properties. Do you want them to be mutable or not?

If yes, then @sasquatch's answer will do.

If not, then you need to ensure a value is assigned to them only once. As you already do that in the struct declaration (the default values), you can't assign new values to them. But being a struct, they don't need to have default values - moreover, struct automatically receive a memberwise initializer. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html

So here is the variant for immutable properties:

```
struct  EHSearch {
    let EHcategory : String
    let EHname : String
}

var  myEHSearch = [EHSearch]()

// Call to dynamically append the results
// Extra argument: 'EHcategory' in call

myEHSearch.append(EHSearch(EHcategory: "Food", EHname: "Joes Crab Shack"))
```

The "Extra Argument" error you're seeing is because the compiler already has values for the properties so it doesn't expect any new ones. Here is the "middle" way - one property has a default value whilst the other doesn't - which should make it clearer:

```
struct  EHSearch {
    let EHcategory : String = ""
    let EHname : String
}

var  myEHSearch = [EHSearch]()

// Call to dynamically append the results
// Extra argument: 'EHcategory' in call

myEHSearch.append(EHSearch(EHname: "Joes Crab Shack"))
```